# Make EditText readonly on text change in another EditText

Tags: java, android

I want to create two editable `EditText` in android. When the user is entering data in one `EditText`, the other `EditText` automatically becomes read-only and shows the result of that entered data.

Answer (score 1):

### Try The Following Code

Consider two EditText e1 and e2

```
 e1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
       e2.setEnabled(false);
        return false;

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code. And apply your logic, first check if this EditText is empty the call this code

```
editText.setEnabled(false);
```

Suppose Your editText is empty then check like this

```
if(editText.getText().toString.isEmpty()){
 editText.setEnabled(false);
 }
```

Comment: @ZaidQureshi please clear your requirement. Surely I will help you

Answer (score 0):

First you set a :-

```
edittext.setFocusable(false);
 edittest.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
```

**OR**

set **android:focusable="false"** in XMl file

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/EditTextInput"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:cursorVisible="true">
    </EditText>
```

Then in edittext's OnStateChangeListener you going to **android:focusable="true"** your next Edittext

```
editText1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

   @Override
   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

   @Override    
   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
     int count, int after) {

   }

   @Override    
   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
     int before, int count) {
      if(s.length() != 0){
         edittext2.setFocusable(true);
         edittest2.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
     }   
   }
  });
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: According to the documentation for .setFocusableInTouchMode() calling .setFocusableInTouchMode(true) makes calling .setFocusable(true) unnecessary. I.e. you only need to call etAdd.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

Comment: @ZaidQureshi try this code or in this same edittext's override method you can enable/disable edittext by using  edit.setEnabled(true); by default you set all edittext to enable="false"

Answer (score 0):

Use this and in `onTextChanged` set the data in `editText` you will get the your desired results.

```
yourEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

                }
            });
```

`setEnabled false or true` in `afterTextChanged`. do whatever you want according to your need

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
editText1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                editText2.setEnabled(false);
                editText2.setText(editText1.getText().toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            }
        });
```

Set text watcher to your `editText`, and make them enabled/disabled when one of them is typed.
It should be ok in this way.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

> when the user wants to put data in one editText the other
>   automatically becomes read-only dynamically to show the result

Use text watcher to your EditText, and make other edit text enabled/disabled when user typed on first EditText

```
EditText editText1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.text1);
EditText editText2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.text2);

editText1 .addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    editText2.setEnabled(false);

    //calculate and display result of that entered data
    editText2.setText("your result");

            } 
});
```